# Obtaining an ID provide a name of an Object of a Class

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is too basic or just an impossible question.

I have a class (Student) with two data members named 'id' and 'name'. Both are unique for each object.

Provided a name can and how do I get an id related to an object with that particular name?

I know that there is an object with the provided name but I do not have a search space to look for an object's id with that name.

Comment: Do you have a collection of these objects somewhere? Can you show any code?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any code as I am still in designing mode. I was wondering that this might not even be possible to search for an ID using a name if I don't have objects list.

Comment: I would be having a collection of objects but I wont be having these objects list by their names. The thing I know is that there would surely be an object by a provided name.

Comment: Do you want search for an id by name in a collection of Student objects?

Comment: @Vinicius Yes that is what I want to do. But I don't have objects list by their names.

Comment: Do you have a collection, right?

Comment: If you have the objects in a list, yes you can write something like: `list.First(s => s.Name == "Bob").Id;`

Comment: No sorry for the confusion. I do not have a list or collection.

Comment: could you  give an example code?

Comment: So... what do you have? Just a bunch of member variables?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering whether I can treat a Class as a Table in a Database and somehow extract the ID by using a name.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Now I do have obtained a list. Can you tell me a way forward from here?

Comment: Did you try the previous snippet? Its the same as the answer one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
var id = yourList.First(s => s.Name == "value").Id;
```

Comment: I do not have a list. I do not have a sample code either as I am still designing a way to go about the solution.